# Why DNS lookup take a lot of time in local?

Tags: nginx, dns, localhost

In order to have a quite "similar" approach in local and production, I set up an NGINX that proxy the request to `localhost:port`. In production it redirects from `subdomain.example.com` to `localhost:port`. In local it redirects from `subdomain.example.local` to `localhost:port` and I changed my host according to :

```
127.0.0.1 sub1.example.local
127.0.0.1 sub2.example.local
.
.
.
```

When I'm testing my builds Front-Ends, DNS lookup took a lot of time (10+ seconds) and I wonder why.

[image: chrome network screen]

Thoughts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved and was related to chrome optimization module (~DNS prefetching) :

If you face this problem, go to :

- settings >> advance >> privacy and security
- disable “Use a prediction service to load pages more quickly”

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have more than two nameservers entries in  `/etc/resolv.conf`, and when testing the first name server is used but could be that your records are not being found in that server, therefore uses the second one.

To speed up this process, this can be added in `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
options timeout:1 attempts:2
```

From the [man](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?resolv.conf):

```
timeout:n     sets the  initial amount of time the resolver
              will wait for a response  from a remote name
              server before retrying the query  via a differ-
              ent name  server. 

attempts:n    sets the  number of times the resolver will send
              a query to each of its name servers before giv-
              ing up and returning an error to  the calling
              application.
```

Another way to speed up more things is to add your domains to `/etc/hosts` for example:

```
1.2.3.4    www.example.com
127.0.0.1  foo.local bar.local sub1.example.local
```

Comment: Mac OS X Notice =>
This file is not used by the host name and address resolution or the DNS query routing mechanisms used by most processes on
this Mac OS X system. This file is automatically generated.
=>
That means that I can't edit since it will be override I guess ?

Comment: Give a try to `/etc/hosts` also check this post https://serverfault.com/q/478534/94862

Comment: It seems that the problem is chrome related because when I ping sub1.example.local it's very fast. But took 10s in chrome